# How to save partial in redis and then render it multipe time in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have partial that have application helper method. I take long time to rendered.
So how optimize this rendering time by save this partial in redis ?
How to render partial in multiple time in app ?

Comment: You need to read up on caching (that's the term). Rails has good support for it.

Comment: Thanks Sergio. Can you please explain how to caching partial in redis or without redis ?

Comment: just cache the rendered result, not the partial template itself.

Comment: Hi Sergio, If I update my partial, in that case its not working :(